# How to find Places near a certain location

Tags: quickblox

I know how to add a place and get all the places but in android how do i find the places near a certain location (lati, long).

I see that a Place has a geodata associated with it and I can retrieve geodatas near a certain location but the API to retrieve geodata only retrieves users near a certain location but not places.

So in android is it possible to find places near a certain location (just like I can find users near a certain location)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do it:

- load all places and sort in on mobile side
- Use GeoData as a Place entity